# I have complex Spec for my data - how to generate samples?

Tags: clojure, specifications

My Clojure spec looks like :

```
(spec/def ::global-id string?)
(spec/def ::part-of string?)
(spec/def ::type string?)
(spec/def ::value string?)
(spec/def ::name string?)
(spec/def ::text string?)
(spec/def ::date (spec/nilable (spec/and string? #(re-matches #"^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$" %))))
(spec/def ::interaction-name string?)
(spec/def ::center (spec/coll-of string? :kind vector? :count 2))
(spec/def ::context- (spec/keys :req [::global-id ::type]
                                :opt [::part-of ::center]))
(spec/def ::contexts (spec/coll-of ::context-))
(spec/def ::datasource string?)
(spec/def ::datasource- (spec/nilable (spec/keys :req [::global-id ::name])))
(spec/def ::datasources (spec/coll-of ::datasource-))
(spec/def ::location string?)
(spec/def ::location-meaning- (spec/keys :req [::global-id ::location ::contexts ::type]))
(spec/def ::location-meanings (spec/coll-of ::location-meaning-))
(spec/def ::context string?)
(spec/def ::context-association-type string?)
(spec/def ::context-association-name string?)
(spec/def ::priority string?)
(spec/def ::has-context- (spec/keys :req [::context ::context-association-type ::context-association-name ::priority]))
(spec/def ::has-contexts (spec/coll-of ::has-context-))
(spec/def ::fact- (spec/keys :req [::global-id ::type ::name ::value]))
(spec/def ::facts (spec/coll-of ::fact-))
(spec/def ::attribute- (spec/keys :req [::name ::type ::value]))
(spec/def ::attributes (spec/coll-of ::attribute-))
(spec/def ::fulltext (spec/keys :req [::global-id ::text]))
(spec/def ::feature- (spec/keys :req [::global-id ::date ::location-meanings ::has-contexts ::facts ::attributes ::interaction-name]
                                :opt [::fulltext]))
(spec/def ::features (spec/coll-of ::feature-))
(spec/def ::attribute- (spec/keys :req [::name ::type ::value]))
(spec/def ::attributes (spec/coll-of ::attribute-))
(spec/def ::ioi-slice string?)
(spec/def ::ioi- (spec/keys :req [::global-id ::type ::datasource ::features ::attributes ::ioi-slice]))
(spec/def ::iois (spec/coll-of ::ioi-))
(spec/def ::data (spec/keys :req [::contexts ::datasources ::iois]))
(spec/def ::data- ::data)
```

But it fails to generate samples with:

```
(spec/fdef data->graph
  :args (spec/cat :data ::xml-spec/data-))

(println (stest/check `data->graph))
```

then it will fail to generate with an exception:
`Couldn't satisfy such-that predicate after 100 tries.`

It is very convenient to generate spec automatically with `stest/check` but how to beside spec also have generators?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you see the error `Couldn't satisfy such-that predicate after 100 tries.` when generating data from specs, a common cause is an `s/and` spec because spec builds generators for `s/and` specs based solely on the *first* inner spec.

This spec seemed most likely to cause this, because the first inner spec/predicate in the `s/and` is `string?`, and the following predicate is a regex:

```
(s/def ::date (s/nilable (s/and string? #(re-matches #"^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$" %))))
```

If you sample a `string?` generator, you'll see what it produces is unlikely to ever match your regex:

```
(gen/sample (s/gen string?))
=> ("" "" "X" "" "" "hT9" "7x97" "S" "9" "1Z")
```

test.check will try (100 times by default) to get a value that satisfies `such-that` conditions, then throw the exception you're seeing if it doesn't.

### Generating Dates

You can implement a custom generator for this spec in several ways. Here's a test.check generator that will create ISO local date strings:

```
(def gen-local-date-str
  (let [day-range (.range (ChronoField/EPOCH_DAY))
        day-min (.getMinimum day-range)
        day-max (.getMaximum day-range)]
    (gen/fmap #(str (LocalDate/ofEpochDay %))
              (gen/large-integer* {:min day-min :max day-max}))))
```

This approach gets the range of valid epoch days, uses that to control the range of `large-integer*` generator, then `fmap`s `LocalDate/ofEpochDay` over the generated integers.

```
(def gen-local-date-str
  (gen/fmap #(-> (Instant/ofEpochMilli %)
                 (LocalDateTime/ofInstant ZoneOffset/UTC)
                 (.toLocalDate)
                 (str))
            gen/large-integer))
```

This starts with the default `large-integer` generator and uses `fmap` to provide a function that creates a `java.time.Instant` from the generated integer, converts it to a `java.time.LocalDate`, and converts that to a string which happens to conveniently match your date string format. (This is slightly simpler on Java 9 and above with `java.time.LocalDate/ofInstant`.)

Another approach might use test.chuck's [regex-based string generator](https://github.com/gfredericks/test.chuck#string-from-regex), or different date classes/formatters. Note that both of my examples will generate years that are eons before/after -9999/+9999, which won't match your `\d{4}` year regex, but the generator should produce satisfactory values often enough that it may not matter for your use case. There are many ways to generate date values!

```
(gen/sample gen-local-date-str)
=>
("1969-12-31"
 "1970-01-01"
 "1970-01-01"
 ...)
```

### Using Custom Generators with Specs

Then you can associate this generator with your spec using `s/with-gen`:

```
(s/def ::date
  (s/nilable
   (s/with-gen
    (s/and string? #(re-matches #"^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$" %))
    (constantly gen-local-date-str))))

(gen/sample (s/gen ::date))
=>
("1969-12-31"
 nil ;; note that it also makes nils b/c it's wrapped in s/nilable
 "1970-01-01"
 ...)
```

You can also provide "standalone" custom generators to certain spec functions that take an *overrides* map, if you don't want to tie the custom generator directly to the spec definition:

```
(gen/sample (s/gen ::data {::date (constantly gen-local-date-str)}))
```

Using this spec and generator I was able to generate your larger `::data` spec, although the outputs were *very* large due to some of the collection specs. You can also control the size of those during generation using `:gen-max` options in the specs.

Comment: Great answer! I would suggest a small fix though: I think you forgot to put `gen/large-integer` between parentheses in the second version of the generator, the `Instant`-based one. I believe `gen/large-integer` is not itself a generator even though it returns one when called.

Comment: @RoneyGomes I had to double check, but `gen/large-integer` is a generator value — the result of `(large-integer* {})` (see [here](https://github.com/clojure/test.check/blob/28a73051ba84a4e5a915d4e4ab2ef0a1c489093a/src/main/clojure/clojure/test/check/generators.cljc#L1020)) — so the example works as-is. Thanks!

Comment: Weird... I got `Assert failed: Second arg to fmap must be a generator (generator? gen)` when calling it without the parentheses. Must've got something wrong. ‍♀️